# Cayley Hamilton Theorem using LU decompostion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find the characterisitic equation of n*n matrix by Cayley Hamilton Theorem using LU Decompostion. Below is my algorithm to find U matrix.

```
void LU_decompose(RPoly **A,int n) {

RPoly L[n][n];
for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k) {

    for (int i = k + 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        L[i][k] = RPoly::div(A[i][k],A[k][k]);
    }
    for (int j = k+1; j < n; ++j)
    {
        for (int i = k+1; i < n; ++i)
        {
            A[i][j] = RPoly::sub(A[i][j], RPoly::mul(L[j][k],A[k][j]));
        }
    }
}}
```

Here, I am storing each element of the matrix as a rational polynomial i.e., each RPoly object has a numerator polynomial and a denominator polynomial. The division operation looks like this.

```
static RPoly div(RPoly a, RPoly b)
{
    Poly dr = Poly::multiply(a.dr,b.nr);
    Poly nr = Poly::multiply(a.nr,b.dr);
    RPoly ans(nr,dr);
    return ans;
}
```

The problem is finding the product of the dialogonal elements of U matrix in the end. For a 2*2 matrix I can simply strike out nr,dr and print the result. For a 3*3 matrix I am not able to reduce the charactersitic equation to a degree of n. Am I proceeding in the right way? Is there any better approach? Plese help. Thanks